# Android Volley: Headers are not appended

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley

I am trying to implement tokenization in my Android app, and for that I always need to add the authorization header to my request anytime I make one to the server. The problem is that when I debug the server instance, even if the request is made, there is no Authorization header added in it that

Here is my code

```
private void syncDatabases()
{
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String uri = "random_url";
    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait while syncing");
    pDialog.show();

    List<Plane> allPlane = service.gettAllPlane();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();

    for (Plane p : allPlane)
    {
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(p);
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            obj.remove("ID");
            jsArray.put(obj);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri, jsArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
        {
            ArrayList<Plane> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            try
            {
                for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                {
                    String planeName,planeEngine,planeProducer,planeCountry,planeYear,wikiLink,ID;
                    JSONObject pl = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String p1 = pl.optString("ID");
                    if (pl != null && !p1.isEmpty())
                        ID = pl.getString("ID");
                    else
                        ID = "0";

                    String p2 = pl.optString("planeName");
                    if (p2 != null && !p2.isEmpty())
                        planeName = pl.getString("planeName");
                    else
                        planeName = "";

                    String p3 = pl.optString("planeEngine");
                    if (p3 != null && !p3.isEmpty())
                        planeEngine = pl.getString("planeEngine");
                    else
                        planeEngine = "";

                    String p4 = pl.optString("planeProducer");
                    if (p4 != null && !p4.isEmpty())
                        planeProducer = pl.getString("planeProducer");
                    else
                        planeProducer = "";

                    String p5 = pl.optString("planeCountry");
                    if (p5 != null && !p5.isEmpty())
                        planeCountry = pl.getString("planeCountry");
                    else
                        planeCountry = "";

                    String p6 = pl.optString("planeYear");
                    if (p6 != null && !p6.isEmpty())
                        planeYear = pl.getString("planeYear");
                    else
                        planeYear = "0";

                    String p7 = pl.optString("wikiLink");
                    if (p7 != null && !p7.isEmpty())
                        wikiLink = pl.getString("wikiLink");
                    else
                        wikiLink = "";

                    Plane plf = new Plane(Integer.parseInt(ID),planeName,planeEngine,planeProducer,planeCountry,Integer.parseInt(planeYear),wikiLink);
                    newList.add(plf);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            service.deleteAllFromPlane();
            for (Plane p : newList)
            {
                boolean ok = service.addNewPlane(p);
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
            tab1.onIorU();

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred ", error);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            String auth_token_string = settings.getString("token", "");

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            params.put("Authorization", auth_token_string);
            return params;
        }
    };
```

I already verified if auth_token_string is null (it isn't). Here is what I see on the server side (C# Web API 2 server)
[image]

And here is how I get the header:

```
var authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;
```

In the pic you can see a part of the token I try to send in the headers field though. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: i see a `getHeaders()` method. But it is never called. Where do you attach the headers.

Comment: It is auto-called (if you add a breakpoint in there it will trigger itself). Also you can see the token was somehow added in the pic I posted, in the Headers section).

Comment: try hard coding the value in the request. This will help you figure out whether the your able to fetch the string from ui or not. The code looks correct. And also try it out after removing  params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: I would log what is inside `auth_token_string`, is it null or blank? As you said, its attaching the header, just no value. The value may be the problem.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that the token is attached and I can see it in the debugger (look in the pic at the header section, you can see a bit of the token).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your authorization token you are missing Type of authorization. I am asuming that you are using Bacis auth, so try using this:

```
params.put("Authorization", "Basic " + auth_token_string);
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you :)